# Як називається геометрична фігура українською?

Tags: словотворення

У прямокутному квадраті може вміститись одне коло, яке є найбільшим та яке торкається 4-х сторін квадрата, 
як називаються 4-и фігури з кутами та дугою від кола, які є поза колом в квадраті, де фігури з кутами в 90 градусів складають дві однакові лінії та дугу кола?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до Ukrainian.SE! Цікаве запитання) Можливо, ви знаєте, як ця фігура називаються англійською? Так нам буде легше знайти український відповідник.

Comment: оффтоп, принаймні з таким описом.

Comment: ця фігура - трикутник з вігнутою до прямого кута гіпотинузою, тобто в середину. Такий "трикутник" підкладають під колеса автомобілів щоб вони нерухалися. Важлива фігура яка робить з кола квадрат, а от назва...

Comment: Думаю, це не зовсім on-topic для цього сайту. Питання для самоперевірки: чи може абстрактна людина, яка вважається «фахівцем з української мови», відповісти на це запитання? Відповідь — ні, не може. На це запитання може відповісти математик.